# How can I hide below mentioned div tag in vue js

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

I wanted to hide div tag which contains label and input field.(house name or number) whenever i click on enter address manually (PFA ).

**After click on enter manually-**
[image: After click on enter manually]

**Before click on enter manually-**

[image: Before click on enter manually]

Comment: please provide a code with this screenshot

Comment: Please also provide a description of exactly when the element should and should not be hidden.

Comment: @BhushanGunjal You can use the `v-if` or `v-show` directive to achieve this. Please take a look at the answer I provided below.

Comment: Did my answer help you @BhushanGunjal ? Would love some feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

You can hide/show elements based on a variable by using the `v-if` directive, and change the state with a simple method. This is called `Conditional Rendering`.
I suppose OP uses single file template syntax since not stated otherwise.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="box-to-hide" v-if="showBox">
    <div class="button" @click="toggleShowBox">Enter manually</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        showBox : false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      toggleShowBox() {
        this.showBox = !this.showBox;
      }
    }
  };

</sript>
```

You can find more details about `v-if` in the official vue guide https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html .

### v-if vs. v-show

You can also use `v-show` directive.

```html
<h1 v-show="ok">Hello!</h1>
```

The difference is that an element with v-show will always be rendered and remain in the DOM; v-show only toggles the display CSS property of the element.